# How to push front in linked list Rust?

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement linked list in Rust. My code:

```
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Clone, Debug)]
struct ListNode {
    val: i32,
    next: Option<Box<ListNode>>
}
impl ListNode {
    fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        println!("Call new {}", val);
        return ListNode {
            val: val,
            next: None
        };
    }

    fn push_front(self, &mut new_head: &mut ListNode) -> ListNode {
        new_head.next = Some(Box::new(self));
        return  new_head;
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut node1 = ListNode::new(1); 
    let mut node2 = ListNode::new(2);
    node2 = node1.push_front(&mut node2);   
}
```

I have an error in

> error[E0507]: cannot move out of a mutable reference: fn push_front(self, &mut new_head: &mut ListNode) -> ListNode {

How can I fix the error? I think that Copytrait implementation is not a good idea

Comment: You modify `new_head` in place, there is no need to return it as well.

Comment: PSA: Rust has an implicit `return`, so you can just `new_head` on the last line and it's equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're directly returning `ListNode` from `push_front`, which means that the return value will be moved out. But you cannot move the data when you only have a reference.

If you are sure that you want the caller to take ownership, you can allow the `new_head` argument to be moved into the function too.

```
impl ListNode {
    // ...
    fn push_front(self, mut new_head: ListNode) -> ListNode {
        new_head.next = Some(Box::new(self));
        new_head
    }
}

fn main() {
    let node1 = ListNode::new(1);
    let mut node2 = ListNode::new(2);
    node2 = node1.push_front(node2);
    println!("{node2:?}");
}
```

Comment: Can also `println!("{node2:?}")` on current versions of Rust.

Comment: @Unmitigated could you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76697406/how-to-reverse-part-of-linked-list-in-rust